# chrome 85.0.4183.121 not showing webpack node in the tree

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, webpack

I use chrome to debug my angular application. I don't know why the webpack node does not show in the tree. So I can't directly to debug my source code. But it shows a different node `webpack-internal`.

I am sure that in my `tsconfig.json` there is

```
"sourceMap": "true"
```

There was `webpack` node, now it is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps

I don't know why Enable SourceMap was disabled. Click it then it works.